# Vuetify framework: Toggle a badge from within a function

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, toggle, vuetify.js

I need to toggle a badge through a function called *openNotifications*. Currently the badge can only be toggled from a button.

Button:

```
<v-btn @click.native="show = !show">toggle badge</v-btn>
```

App.vue:
Open Notifications

```
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      openNotifications () {
        bus.$emit('dialog', true)
      }
[...]
</script>
```

How to toggle the button from within the *openNotifications* function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have the openNotifcations function do the same thing that the @click function is doing, so

```
openNotifications () {
 this.show = !this.show 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I forgot the _this_ part.